# scala function with two implicits string parameters

Tags: scala

I'd like a function to have two implicit parameters, both being strings, such as:

```
def fn(p1: String)(implicit p2: String, p3: String);
```

but this does not work, because it is ambiguous for the compiler.
I tried with traits, but it is not possible for a trait to extend a string, such as:

```
trait P2 extends String
trait P3 extends String
def fn(p1: String)(implicit p2: P2, p3: P3);
```

another solution would be a case class, but then I need to call p2.value, which I don't like

```
case class P2(value: String)
case class P3(value: String)
def fn(p1: String)(implicit p2: P2, p3: P3) { p2.value... }
```

any other solution?

Comment: How about one case class for both strings? You could give them meaningful names. I think there is no better solution to this.

Comment: Can you give us some idea about what your use case is? Without knowing this I don't think it's really possible to make sensible suggestions.

Comment: I smell an XY problem.